# jQuery link nudge and color transform

Tags: jquery, optimization

Hey everyone, I have achieved the effect described in the title using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.button').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'top': '3px' }, 70);
});
$('.button').mouseup(function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'top': '0px' }, 70);
});
$('.button').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 
        color: '#fff',
        backgroundColor: '#000' 
    }, 250);
});
$('.button').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 
        color: '#000',
        backgroundColor: '#fff' 
    }, 250);
});
```

});

I am pretty sure that that this code can be reduced significantly, can anyone help me out? Please note that I want the button to animate when the mouse is clicked and not return to it's original position until the mouse is released.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one thing you don't have to continually re-generate the jQuery object around the ".button" selector:

```
$('.button')
  .mousedown(function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'top': '3px' }, 70);
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'top': '0px' }, 70);
  })
  .hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 
        color: '#fff',
        backgroundColor: '#000' 
    }, 250);
    },
    function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 
        color: '#000',
        backgroundColor: '#fff' 
    }, 250);
  });
```

Doesn't make it much shorter. You could also consider doing this with `live()` or `delegate()` 
instead of dealing with the buttons directly. That's probably what I'd do, since your selector here is cheap to check when an event happens. If you have a lot of buttons (which would probably a bad idea anyway, especially if they're all pulsating and throbbing as you move the mouse around) it can be a little slow to assign all the handlers.

*edit* — fixed thanks to @MvanGeest

Comment: Please do consider that the `hover` is executing twice, which includes one useless occasion.

Comment: I fixed the hover I think - I changed it to take 2 functions by stealing his old "mouseout" code. Is that right?

Comment: It's the same as I did, and right according to the docs. Of course, only he can tell us if it works.

Comment: Thanks, you were both really helpful. I forgot that I could chain the methods instead of referencing the selector each time. Removing the second (unnecessary) hover is great. Although it's not much shorter its definitely an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You're abusing `.hover()`. From the API reference:

> Description: Bind two handlers to the
>   matched elements, to be executed when
>   the mouse pointer enters and leaves
>   the elements.

So this will speed things up:

```
$('.button').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 
        color: '#fff',
        backgroundColor: '#000' 
    }, 250);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 
        color: '#000',
        backgroundColor: '#fff' 
    }, 250);
});
```

But I believe the code cannot really be optimized further. You could use `.bind()` and a hash, but that's only marginally faster/better.